# Intentを使ってアクティビティを推移しようとしたら、例外がスローされず強制終了する

Tags: android, java, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

アクティビティを推移しようとしたら、例外も発生せず強制終了します。

### ソースコード

#### Java

```
//勿論、すべてimport済み
public class FileSelectActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.file_list);
        File file=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String[] string_list=file.list();
        file=null;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        arrayAdapter.addAll(string_list);
        string_list=null;
        ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.selectfile_list);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

### レイアウト(xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selectfile_list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jimdo.solarand.android.droidtexteditor" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FileSelectActivity"/>
         <!--もちろん書いている--->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### テスト環境

関係ないと思いますが…

- Asus MemoPad 8 me181cでテスト。
- Android4.4
- RAM:876MB 空き:230MBくらい？
- ROM:16GB 残り:4.87GB

## つまり、何をして欲しいか

強制終了しないようにして欲しいです。
何故かが推測できる方、教えて下さい。

## 追加情報:

このコードが原因のようです。

```
arrayAdapter.addAll(string_list);
```

ブリークポイントが使えないので1行一行

```
Log.v("Code Debug","Code(super.onCreate()など…)");
```

で調べました。
ArrayAdapter.addAll();の使い方はこれで良いのでしょうか。

Comment: string_listは配列、addAllはCollectionを引数にとります。java.util.Arrays.asListなど使ったらどうなりますか

Comment: addAllってコレクションが引数だったんですね！なぜコンパイルエラーにならなかったのか不思議ですがやってみます。

Comment: と思ったら引数がT[]のメソッドがありました。すみません。

Comment: Listでもダメでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSelectActivity#onCreate()の1行目にbreakpointを設置してデバッグしてみてください。
breadpointで止まればそこまでは動いているので、1行ずつ進めてどこで落ちるか確認できると思います。
breakpointに達しなければそれ以前の問題です。
終了した際にLogcatには何も出力されませんか？

Comment: Logcat見たかったのですがパソコンが壊れてて…Root化済みなんで頑張ってみます。

Comment: LogCatではNullPointerExceptionと表示されました。(Log.vで表示させた)質問の幅が大きくなってしまうのでどうしてstring_listがnullなのかを別で質問してみます

Answer (score 1):

原因は権限をManifestに書いてないからだと思います
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jimdo.solarand.android.droidtexteditor" >
    <!-- 追加 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FileSelectActivity"/>
         <!--もちろん書いている--->
　　</application>
</manifest>
```

権限許可しただけではおそらくUnSupportedOperationExceptionで落ちます
http://workpiles.com/2014/02/android-arrayadapter-exception/ を参考に
**Java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    String[] string_list = file.list();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  new ArrayList<String>());
    if (string_list != null) {
        arrayAdapter.addAll(Arrays.asList(string_list));
    } else {
        Log.d("onCreate", "string_list is  null");
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.select_file_list);
    if (listView != null) listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```